# Conditional Formatting, access expression that checks if value is on 3rd line of field with carriage returns

Tags: ms-access, expression, conditional-formatting

I have created a matrix query for a report which concatenates multiple fields with carriage returns:

```
TheValue: Max([CLCraftLevel]) & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Max([CTrainingLevel]) & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Max([CSignatory]) & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Max([CAuthDate]) & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & First([CAuthorisedBy])
```

The result of this can look like this ([] being lines with no value):

1

[]

S

19/01/2021

Job Bloggs

or this:

[]

2

[]

[]

[]

or this:

[]

[]

S

19/10/2021

Job Bloggs

If the third line has an "S" then I need the conditional formatting to turn the field blue in my report then if the second line has a "2" and the third line doesn't have an "S" then I need the conditional formatting to turn the field yellow.
I have tried many options for expressions and got the most luck with this:

```
Left(Mid$([Col8],4,InStrRev([Col8],Chr(13))-1),1)="2"
```

But I have to change the 4 based on how many lines are populated it seems.
I do not usually use expressions so am a bit lost.  I would also be open to using a vba solution if that is a better way to do this.

Comment: By 'matrix' do you mean a CROSSTAB query? Why does expression reference [Col8] and not [TheValue] fieldname?

Comment: Sorry, yes a crosstab.  TheValue is the field name in the query.  [Col8] is the control in the report the contains TheValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest using a VBA custom function. Split() function parses a string to a zero-based one-dimensional array (third line will be element index 2). Since it is known which array element to look at (looping array to accomplish something is not necessary), don't need a full array object.

```
Function GetColor(s As String)
If Split(s, vbCrLf)(2) = "S" Then
    GetColor = "Blue"
ElseIf Split(s, vbCrLf)(1) = 2 Then
    GetColor = "Yellow"
End If
End Function
```

Call that function from Conditional Formatting rules:
Expression is: `GetColor([Col8])="Blue"`
Expression is: `GetColor([Col8])="Yellow"`

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much @June7 !